# Is $f(x)$ continuous on $B_{R'}(x_0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le M(R)|x_1-x_2|$, for all $x_1,x_2 \in B_R(x_0)$. ($B_R(x_0)$ is an open neighborhood of $x_0$). M(R) is a function of R. It's positive and approaches $\infty$ when R approaches R'.
I can see that $f(x) $ is continuous on $B_R(x_0)$, when $R < R'$. Is $f(x) $ continuous on $B_{R'}(x_0)$ ?

Comment: continuity is defined locally, right? $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous, but $|\frac {f(x)-f(y)} {x-y}|$ would be asymptotically increasing as you fix $x$ and take $y$ further apart towards any of the infinities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in B_{R'}(x_0)$ and let 
$$
R=\frac{|x-x_0|+R'}{2}<R'.
$$
Since $|x-x_0|<R<R'$ it follows that $x\in B_{R}(x_0)$ and that $f$ is (Lipschitz) continuous on $B_{R}(x_0)$.  Thus $f$ is continuous at an arbitrary point $x\in B_{R'}(x_0)$.